# Read a single file with multiple BufferedReaders

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I'm working on a program that needs to update a line that depends its value on the result of a line that goes read after. I thought that I could use two BufferedReaders in Java to position the reader on the line to update while the other one goes for the line that fixes the value (it can be an unknown number of lines ahead). The problem here is that I'm using two BufferedReaders on the same file and even if I think I'm doing right with the indexes the result in debug doesn't seem to be reliable.
Here's the code:

```
            String outFinal
            FileName=fileOut;

        File fileDest=new File(outFinalFileName);
        try {
            fout = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream(fileDest)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileReader inputFile=null;

        try {
            inputFile = new FileReader(inFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        BufferedReader finChecker = new BufferedReader(inputFile);  //Checks the file and matches record to change
        String line="";
        String lineC="";
        int lineNumber=0;
        String recordType="";
        String statusCode="";
        try {
            while ((lineC = finChecker.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;
                if (lineNumber==1)
                    line=fin.readLine();
                recordType=lineC.substring(0,3);//Gets current Record Type
                if (recordType.equals("35")){
                    while(!line.equals(lineC)){
                        line=fin.readLine();
                        if (line==null)
                            break;
                        fout.write(line);


                    }
                }else if (recordType.equals("32")){
                    statusCode=lineC.substring(4,7);
                    if(statusCode.equals("XX")){
                        updateRecordLine(line,fout);
                    }
                }


            }
            returnVal=true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the BufferedReader only reads stuff, it doesn't have the ability to write data back out. So, what you would need is a BufferedReader to get stuff in, and a BufferedWriter that takes all the input from the BufferedReader, and outputs it to a temp file, with the corrected/appended data.

Then, when you're done (i.e. both BufferedReader and BufferedWriter streams are closed), you need to either discard the original file, or rename the temp file to the name of the original file.

You are basically copying the original file to a temp file, modifying the line in question in the temp file's output, and then copying/renaming the temp file over the original.

Comment: No, they're open, I can see that while debugging. However I can't read it all and keep it in memory because this might use large files. My problem is still on the synchronized reading of both BufferedReaders. I see different results for what it'd be supposed to be the same line.

Comment: I don't understand (1) why you need two BufferedReaders, or (2) why you don't just output the file to the temp file as you're reading it (which means you don't have to keep the entire file in memory, just the current line(s) in the file.

Comment: So, if you're reading a file, and you run into a line that needs to have its value changed, depending on the line after, add that line to an array or something, marking it as "needing to be changed", then (with the same BufferedReader) read the next line, compute the change, and write the changed line to the temp file. If I understand the problem correctly, you should be able to do this with just one BufferedReader, a temporary storage for lines you will change, and one BufferedWriter. Can you post an excerpt of the data so we can get an example of what kind of data change you're making?

Comment: Excuse me for my english. The file is composed of multiple record types. Let's call them record 1 and record 6, assuming that the other records between 1 and 6 exist also. Well, when I read record 6 I might find an information that would make me change the last record 1 I have already read. That's why I can't go back and update the value. I have to use another BufferedReader that remains on the last record 1 file and as soon as the record 6 contains that information update and write the record 1. There might be an easier mode, I can't say.

Comment: So, what's the maximum number of records that you'll need to read before you know that a correction is necessary on an earlier line? Whatever that number is, that tells you the maximum size of a data buffer you need to keep in memory. You can alter the data in the buffer as needed, and have the BufferedWriter write data from the buffer. You don't need two BufferedReaders - there are easier ways of keeping track of where you are/buffering data that might need to be changed for later.

Comment: I think you've helped me with the comment above, I can read all the different records between the previous record 1 and the next record 1 and do everything I have to do before writing them out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i see some problem in your code exactly on these lines-->

```
recordType=lineC.substring(0,3);//Gets current Record Type                 
if (recordType.equals("35")){
```

if you see on the first line, you are getting the substring of recordType into recordType. Now recordType length is 3. If at all the recordType has only 2 characters, then substring throws arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So when no runtime exceptions, its length is 3 and on the next line you are calling the equals method that has a string with 2 characters.

Will this if block ever run ?